# Struggling to optimize algorithm with cubic complexity in C#

Tags: c#

This algorithm's time complexity appears to be that of a cubic nature (it has been suggested. to me that it is quadratic, but it appears cubic to me). I've been trying to tackle the problem of reducing its complexity for a while and I am completely stuck. If anyone has any hints or pointers (no pun intended) that would be very helpful. Not looking for a full answer here.

```
var ParentChildList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var parent in Parents) 
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dict.Add(parent.name, new List<int>() {0});

    foreach (var child in parent.Children) {
        var datesOfBirth = child.Pets.Select(x => x.Pet.DateOfBirth.ToString()).ToList();
        var childIds = child.Pets.Select(x => x.ChildId).ToList()

        dict[child.Name] = new
        {
            dateOfBirth = datesOfBirth
            childId = childIds
        }
    }

    ParentChildList.Add(dict);
}
```

where `Parents` is a `List<Parent>`.

Comment: What is the *original problem*, please?

Comment: umm, it seems you can `linq` the problem all the way down. but it stills involve 3 layer of loop in the background at least. i dont think there is a simpler approach - you need to access pet of child from parent after all.

Comment: "Not looking for a full answer here." You're probably in the wrong place then; this is a Question and Answer site, after all, not a Question and some-portion-of-an-answer site...

Comment: @BagusTesa My thoughts exactly on it requiring 3 loops. Im still new to C#, so ill look into `linq`. @DmitryBychenko lol pretty obvious huh; nonetheless there is nothing lost in translation. I altered the classes involved to simplify the problem, I dont see any reason to change it at this point and no its not a homework problem.

Comment: I don't think using linq instead of foreach is going to change the complexity. Can a child have multiple parents? Some work/data could be reused...

Comment: Having name as the key in the dictionary seems strange, what if mutiple parents/children have that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the `foreach` using `linq`, but the performance might not be that different given the need to reach out `Pets` from `Parent`. The following `linq` assumes we keep `Pets` as is for simplicity.

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> ParentChildList  =
      parents.Select(
         parent => parent.Childs
          .Select(child => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(child.Name, child.Pets))
          .Prepend(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(parent.Name, new List<int>(){0}))
          .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
         )
      .ToList();
```

Should you need to keep the `DatesOfBirth` and `ChildId` you can chug it into `child.Pets` using anonymous class.

Keep in mind that this `linq` is not SQL friendly (that `Prepend` and `ToDictionary` do not map to any SQL concept).